# Does fscanf return ASCII '0' when reading empty string?

Tags: c, windows

Ok more code as asked.

```
int serialize_students(const Student *studArray, const int arrLength)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int i=0;

    ptr_file =fopen("output.txt", "w");

    if (!ptr_file)
        return -1;

    for (i=0; i<arrLength; i++)
    {
        fprintf(ptr_file,"%d\n", studArray[i].id);
        fprintf(ptr_file,"%s\n", studArray[i].name);
        fprintf(ptr_file,"%d\n", studArray[i].gender);

    }

    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}

int deserialize_students(Student *dest, const int destCapacityMax)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int i=0;


    ptr_file =fopen("output.txt","r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return -1;

    if(destCapacityMax==0)
        return -2;

    while (!feof (ptr_file))
    {  
        fscanf (ptr_file, "%d", &dest[i].id);    
        fscanf (ptr_file, "%s",  dest[i].name);     
        fscanf (ptr_file, "%d", &dest[i].gender);      
        i++;

        if(i==destCapacityMax)
            return 0;

    }


    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}

void print_student(Student student)
{
    printf("id: %d\n", student.id);
    printf("name: %s\n", student.name);
    printf("gender: %d\n", student.gender);
}

void print_students(const Student *studArray, const int arrLength)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i =0; i<5;i++)
    {
        print_student(studArray[i]);
    }
}
```

main

```
typedef struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[100];
    int gender;
}Student;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    Student dest[5];
    Student students[5];
    memset(dest,0,sizeof(dest));
    memset(students,0,sizeof(students));


    /* Initialize students */
    /*for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        students[i].id = i;
        strcpy(students[i].name,arr[i]);
        students[i].gender = MALE;
    }*/

    /*Serialize*/
    serialize_students(students,5);

    /* Reconstruct student array from file */
    deserialize_students(dest, 5);

    /* Print reconstructed array of students */
    print_students(dest,5);

    return 0;

}
```

My question is: see how the data is written in file, and see how it is printed on console? Why they differ? Why only first three values of name show 0? but other two empty?

This is how file looked like

[image]

This is console output:

[image]

Comment: @MichaelWalz:element of array of type `Student `

Comment: Please update your question and don't post this in comments.

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: Side note: `fscanf (ptr_file, "%s",  dest[i].name);`. Possible buffer overflow when input is longer than `99` characters.

Comment: What platform ar you on ? Windows, Linux, Mac, ... ? How do you open your file ? Please show more code.

Comment: Try `"wt"` and `"rt"` instead of `"w"` and `"r"` in `fopen`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: does not help, did you at least understand the issue?

Comment: Show the definition of `student`.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: I see but how come ASCII '0'-s are written to the name then?

Comment: @userq you should read [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to ask questions, this will save you and us a lot of time for your future questions.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I ahve read it I think my question is clear and complete now. Where does the ASCII '0' come when reading data back?

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question "*Does fscanf return ASCII '0' when reading empty string?*", no, it does not return ASCII zero. It returns the number of fields successfuly read (or EOF in the case of a read error or end-of-file). Since it didn't read any fields from an empty string, it returns integer 0.

For your other question parts I need the print function. But probably, you forget to skip the terminating whitespace (\n) after reading a field.

**EDIT:** Funny....I copied your source into my VC2008 and it ran pefectly. I did not add spaces to the format specifications (which would skip newlines and other whitespace) and `fscanf` just ignored the newlines. I checked the Microsoft documentation and it didn't say anything about that - it shouldnt skip the newlines, but it did. I added a space before and later also after each format specifier to ignore whitespace still in the buffer and that didn't make any difference. I dumped the output and there were neat `0x0D, 0x0A` CR/LF pairs terminating each line. Anyone any suggestions? Or is this a Microsoft anomaly?

**EDIT:** User Freenode-Boston Seb quotes a scanf manual from IEEE stating "*Input white-space characters (as specified by isspace) shall be skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a [, c, C, or n conversion specifier.*" That holds here, so according to this manual your code is fine.

Comment: It returns the number of fields successfuly read (or `EOF` in the case of a read error or end-of-file).

Comment: In your posted code, you commented out the initialization. I put it back in for my testing and the results are fine. If you don't have a proper `output.txt` file anymore, then the results you read will be wrong and so your new `ouput.txt` and console output too.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the `scanf`/`fscanf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html),

> Input white-space characters (as specified by isspace) shall be skipped, unless the conversion specification includes a `[`, `c`, `C`, or `n` conversion specifier.

In other words, prior to your `%d` and `%s` reads, as much whitespace will be read and discarded as possible.

It's important to realise that *these do not read empty fields*! The *empty fields* that you perceive will be discarded as they are parts of streams of whitespace.

`scanf` and `fscanf` aren't really ideal for *line-by-line input*. They're more suitable for *field-by-field input*, `%s` denoting a *word* that is separated by whitespace (and isn't empty) and `%d` denoting a sequence of decimal digit characters, possibly with a leading sign character (and isn't empty).

This will explain why you see string fields that contain `0`, `1`, `42` or whatever other decimal digit sequences you intended to fall into the `int` variables.

Perhaps, if you would spend more time reading and understanding the manuals for functions before you use them, you might have this particular kind of problem, relating to guessing how a function is used, less often in the future...

P.S. Don't forget to check the return value.

Comment: @userq The ten fields in the file are all 0, "0", 0, 0, "0", 0, 0, "0", 0, 0... I'm not sure how I can more clearly explain this: *`%s` does not read blank fields; it **skips** them*! This is consistent with `%d`, too; `%s` skips all leading whitespace before reading a *non-blank* field! In fact, for that reason you don't need the `\n` directive in this code.

Comment: @userq Question: What if you use 42 in place of 0? What happens, then? Feel free to try it and see...

Comment: @userq What makes you think I was *shout*ing? If I were so angry as to *shout*, for a start you're not in my immediate vicinity so you probably wouldn't hear me... Additionally, I wouldn't bother leading you in a positive direction; I'd probably insult and swear at you. I would suggest that like most people (myself included), you aren't so good at inferring emotions from text (hence why I don't do it). Please stop inventing your own emotional tone from my writings, or I might have to demonstrate how annoying that can be by inventing emotional tone from your writings. Doesn't that seem fair?